# SQL - Stored Procedures - get values from subquery

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and `EXEC` call like:

```
EXEC Schedule_InsertReservations 
     @ScheduleID = (SELECT ScheduleID FROM Schedule WHERE Job_No = 'ABC'),
     @ScheduleTaskID = (SELECT ScheduleTaskID FROM ScheduleTasks WHERE (ScheduleID = (SELECT ScheduleID FROM Schedule WHERE Job_No = 'ABC')) AND LibraryTaskID = 247),
     @ResourceID = (SELECT Vendor_ID FROM tblVendors WHERE Vendor_Name = 'Blue Line Taxi')
```

and I am trying to set the values for the stored procedure using sub-queries but I get these errors when I run it:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near '('.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Can I not use sub-queries in stored procedures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why cant you `DECLARE` three `variables` and use it as `parameter` to the procedure.

```
DECLARE @sch_id     INT,--change the datatype based on your schema.
        @Vendor_ID  INT,
        @Sch_TaskID INT

SELECT @sch_id = ScheduleID
FROM   Schedule
WHERE  Job_No = 'ABC'

SELECT @Sch_TaskID = ScheduleTaskID
FROM   ScheduleTasks ST
       INNER JOIN Schedule S
               ON St.ScheduleID = s.ScheduleID
WHERE  s.Job_No = 'ABC'
       AND s.LibraryTaskID = 247 

SELECT @Vendor_ID = Vendor_ID
FROM   tblVendors
WHERE  Vendor_Name = 'Blue Line Taxi'

EXEC Schedule_insertreservations
  @ScheduleID = @sch_id,
  @ScheduleTaskID = @Sch_TaskID,
  @ResourceID = @Vendor_ID
```

Comment: OP - I would recommend not using a subquery like you are to get your ScheduleTaskID. Instead just make an inner join from ScheduleTasks to Schedule on ScheduleID.

Comment: @SeanLange - Done :). Btw will that make any difference in Sql Server

Comment: Well using the subquery approach if the subquery returned two rows it would raise the exception "subquery returned more than 1 row". Given the nature of what we see I doubt it would make any difference but the join sure is cleaner and easier on the eyes. Of course my comment was directed to the OP, not your fine solution. :D

Answer (score 0):

> Execute a stored procedure or function
>
> ```
> [ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]
>     { 
>       [ @return_status = ]
>       { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var } 
>         [ [ @parameter = ] { value 
>                            | @variable [ OUTPUT ] 
>                            | [ DEFAULT ] 
>                            }
>         ]
>       [ ,...n ]
>       [ WITH RECOMPILE ]
>     }
> [;]
> ```
>
> **value**
>   Is the value of the parameter to pass to the module or pass-through command. If parameter names are not specified, parameter values must be supplied in the order defined in the module.
>   ...
>   If the value of a parameter is an *object name*, character string, or qualified by a database name or schema name, the whole name must be enclosed in single quotation marks. If the value of a parameter is a *keyword*, the keyword must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

I think *value* can be just a name of an object or a keyword. and you can't set parameters in that way.

And @FireBlade solution is your solution.